# How to use Windows 7 Style Controls in .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I am trying to make my application use the new style controls but the controls that default into the VS2010 toolbox are not the same. Does anybody know where to get the controls? Are they available to developers or does the painting have to be done with a custom method to replicate the results.

Here are some examples,

This is an image of the tree view I currently have in my application with a solid blue selection style

[image: Old style tree view]

This is the selection style I wish to replicate,

[image: New style tree view]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Check this link :-[Windows Forms Aero
](http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/)